# Using another sound engine

Tags: android, audio, media-player, soundpool, pitch

Im currently working on a project where the audio is a big thing. I have about 20-30, 3-4 secound clips as is supposed to be played (Max two at a time). (Clips are max 180kB each) And im also planing to pitch these clips in real-time.

The standard mediaplayer in android is stable but doesnt have the funcitonality as i want, such as pitching.

I´ve also tried Soundpool. SoundPool supports pitching but is very unstable. With soundpool im using OGG soundfiles, but i keep getting the error: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12. I guess its because these clips are too large?

**Im wondering if there are any other alternatives for another sound engine?
Or if anyone has tips how to avoid soundpool running out of memory?**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `JetBoy` in android [SDK samples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html). It is using `JetPlayer`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried it for a while, but it couldn't really handle the clips. More of a MIDI-player